# Getting memory problem when trying to generate a 2exp(40) matrix

Tags: python, optimization, binary, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to generate all possible binary numbers of length 40, so i used this code:

```
l = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=40))
```

but i get a memory problem where the process was killed, and i am using a powerful machine with 64GB RAM, so is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: What do you need this for? As Selcuk said, you're creating a huge list, 43 trillion 980 billion 465 million 111 thousand 40 elements in total. (≈ ( 0.21 ≈ 1/5 ) × digitized material content of the Library of Congress (as of 2015) (≈ 5.1 PB ), thanks Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: it's a an optimization problem, an @Slcuk gived me the solution, thank you

Comment: Of course you can just iterate lazily, that doesn't change the fact that your program has to iterate **1 trillion 99 billion 511 million 627 thousand 776 times**. I was asking because odds are there is a better algorithm to do this.

Comment: i have a complex problem, and i have to bruteforce it to get the solution

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Do you know how much time and which processor do I need to accomplish a task on this matrix?

Comment: It will take slightly less than 35 years if each operation takes 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to generate a list of 2^40 (i.e. more than 1 trillion) lists with 40 integer elements each. Since Python `int`s are 24 bytes long, even with the most basic assumptions (not counting the list overhead etc) this requires 960 terabytes of RAM.

The solution is **not** to try to convert the generator to a list and use the generator directly:

```
>>> l = itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=40)
>>> l.next()
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> l.next()
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
>>> l.next()
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
...
```

The catch is you can't do `len(l)` (but you already know the result, don't you?) and you can't slice it.